# jquery modal is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

jquery modal working when code is in same page

**index.jsp**

```
<script>
    function show()
    {
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Demo" onClick="show()" >
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Demo" style="display:none">
    <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>
```

but, when i'm trying to separate the above code in different file, then it is not showing

**index.jsp**

```
   <script>
    function show()
    {
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "/dialog.jsp#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Demo" onClick="show()" >
</body>
```

**dialog.jsp**

```
<div id="#dialog-modal" title="Demo">
    <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>
```

thanks in advance !!

Comment: "it is not working" is not a very descriptive explanation of the problem. Please be more precise.

Comment: i mean.. it is not showing the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call an external resource in a jQuery selector like `$("/dialog.jsp#...")`. Instead you need to load the resource with an AJAX call.

First, add a node to your main HTML to receive it. I've added `<div id='dialog-content'></div>`. Then load the `.dialog()` on that node:

```
   <script>
    function show()
    {
      $(function() {
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-content" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            // Use load function to populate the dialog:
            load: function() {
              $("#dialog-content").load("/dialog.jsp#dialog-modal")
            }
        });
      });
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='dialog-content'></div>
<input type="button" value="Demo" onClick="show()" >
</body>
```

Comment: @sql_query Now working, how? What's it doing or not doing? Also make sure you have my latest, since I edited it a coupleof times.

Comment: $("#dialog-content").load(/"dialog.jsp#dialog-modal") found the problem in the code, it should be   $("#dialog-content").load("/dialog.jsp#dialog-modal"). Now, i correct it, but the problem is, contents of the dialog.jsp is not showing in the dialog. Why..??

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not going to work; jQuery is not going to load the other page fragment for you just because you reference it with that selector; it's not even valid selector syntax.

If you want to load the dialog from another file, you'll have to either do a `<jsp:include>` to include it server-side or else make an explicit ajax call (with jQuery `.load()` or `.ajax()` or whatever) when something happens that makes you want to show the dialog.

Comment: Like I said, either `<jsp:include>` if you want to incorporate the page fragment when your JSP is processed initially, or else with ajax. You haven't provided enough information to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is not element in the dom with the id "dialog-modal'. Your selector is incorrect. Do a console log of your jquery selector result and you'll see it's empty. Make sure the element in loaded in the dom. You can also create it on the fly:

```
$('<div id="my-popup">').dialog({
 height: 140,
 modal: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "path" to your jQuery selector does not put the javascript in a separate file, and I don't think I've seen a successful use of having your HMTL markup in a separate file.

Move the markup back to index.jsp and move the `show()` function into a seperate .js (not .jsp) file.

Link the new .js file to index.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/show.js"></script
```